# How to hide some dynamically generated div's in VueJS v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I hide dynamically generated div elements in VueJS? I have a chatbot application whereby the messages are sent in a prop called `messages`, this messages array is iterated through and it's information is displayed on the screen in multiple Div's. One of the Div's which is generated is used to gauge whether they liked the response or not. Ideally, once the user has selected either "Yes" or "No", then that specific response option box would disappear, however all of the solutions I've tried so far cause all of the response option boxes to disappear.

I've tried adding the !isHidden property on the div and then toggling it on either button click. But when I do that, every single response option box disappears, and no new ones appear either.

I've also assigned a dynamic ID with the intention of hiding the specific div using that, which is how I'd have solved this using Vanilla JavaScript. But I'm struggling to target specific Div's by their ID as I keep getting null in the console.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

I've included a screenshot of the UI, aswell as the code (I've highlighted the specific piece of code which I would like to disappear for each message after clicked).

The last image shows the exact divs I want to hide, e.g. if I wanted to hide `messageResponseSatisfactionOption3` and `messageResponseSatisfactionOption6` after they have been clicked. Sorry for the blocking out of a lot of the image, this is for a project at university.

[UI of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h4Xf.png)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcTUN.png)

[UI image with element console open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOGyy.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please add a piece of code on how you are iterating and on what please

Comment: @GirlCodes I've added another image showing the exact divs I'd like to hide on button click: 'messageResponseSatisfactionOption3' and 'messageResponseSatisfactionOption6', also the first image shows the 'messages' prop which is being iterated over. Is this what you were asking for? :)

Comment: To understand perfectly v-if="message.isStatisfationResponseRequired" and toggeling this specific boolean doesnt work?

Comment: @GirlCodes thanks for your reply, and nope that if statement is only used to decide whether the response option should be shown or not, as it's only shown on certain responses.

Comment: Isn't that what you are trying to do? you want the response to either be shown or not?

Comment: @GirlCodes apologies if I didn't make myself clear in the question description. I'd like the response option to be shown, but then I want it to be hidden once I click either the yes or no button.

Comment: Now i understood but you can use it the same way and change that same prop to hide it if you dont wanna do that you can add another value isStatisfationResponseAnswered and use both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if the message is

```
message: {id: 1, name: "name", side: "side", isStatisfationResponseRequired: true,isStatisfationResponseAnswered: false,...}
```

And on the element you have:

```
<div :id="'messageResponseSatisfactionOption' + message.id" v-if="isStatisfationResponseRequired(message.isStatisfationResponseRequired,message.id)&&!isStatisfationResponseAnswered">
```

and in the method after they response and you want it to be removed you pass for example the index of the message in the list and inside the method you do :

```
hideResponse(index) {
    this.messages[index].isStatisfationResponseAnswered= false;
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue! I never considered toggling the boolean property in the message as I thought hiding the div would be the better solution, but your solution is certainly better. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome i'm glad i could help but you can also use another boolean like ```showStatisfationResponse``` and toggle that and add a ```:class="{'hidden':showStatisfationResponse}" ``` and the class has display none